# Erro ao usar Middleware no Laravel/Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

Fala pessoal estou com o seguinte erro:

```
ReflectionException
Class Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies does not exist
```

Estou usando Lumen mas creio que posso ter configurado algo errado no app.php:

```
$app->middleware([
   Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
   Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
   Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
   Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
   //Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
]);

$app->routeMiddleware([
//     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
```

Comment: Qual versão do Lumen você está utilizando?

Comment: Laravel Lumen 5.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que esses *middlewares* listados existiam só na versão 5.0 do [`bootstrap/app.php`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/5.0/bootstrap/app.php) e foram removidos nas versões posteriores.

No Lumen 5.6 esse trecho de *middlewares* está dessa forma:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/
// $app->middleware([
//    App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
// ]);
// $app->routeMiddleware([
//     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
// ]);
```

Tente comentar esses middlewares e veja se funciona. Verifique também o [*upgrade guide*](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade) caso exista mais alguma alteração.

Comment: Muito obrigado gmsantos, resolveu o problema.

Comment: @EltonSilva que bom! Marcar a resposta como aceita também é um bom sinal de agradecimento. :)